# Beacons in Android - error in tutorial

Tags: java, android

I'm currently working with the [Android Beacons tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/hello-beacons/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#6), and it appears to be something wrong with the code. This method is directly copied from the tutorial, but there is a closing bracket missing after `build()` method. I have tried different solutions, but without success this far.

```
private void subscribe() {
    if (mSubscribed) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Already subscribed.");
        return;
    }

    SubscribeOptions options = new SubscribeOptions.Builder()
            .setStrategy(Strategy.BLE_ONLY)
            // Note: If no filter is specified, Nearby will return all of your
            // attachments regardless of type. You must use a filter to specify
            // a particular set of attachments (by type) or to fetch attachments
            // in a namespace other than your project's default.
            .setFilter(new MessageFilter.Builder()
                .includeNamespacedType("some_namespace", "some_type")
            .build();

    Nearby.Messages.subscribe(mGoogleApiClient, getPendingIntent(), options)
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                    if (status.isSuccess()) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Subscribed successfully.");
                        startService(getBackgroundSubscribeServiceIntent());
                    } else {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Operation failed. Error: " +
                                NearbyMessagesStatusCodes.getStatusCodeString(
                                        status.getStatusCode()));
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Thank you for any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there should be two calls to `build()`, one for the `MessageFilter.Builder` and one for the `SubscribeOptions.Builder`.

Try this:

```
    SubscribeOptions options = new SubscribeOptions.Builder()
        .setStrategy(Strategy.BLE_ONLY)
        // Note: If no filter is specified, Nearby will return all of your
        // attachments regardless of type. You must use a filter to specify
        // a particular set of attachments (by type) or to fetch attachments
        // in a namespace other than your project's default.
        .setFilter(new MessageFilter.Builder()
            .includeNamespacedType("some_namespace", "some_type")
            .build())
        .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

It works, for someone who have a "Cannot resolve method subscribe..."

tks to Fiddler !!!!!!

```
 SubscribeOptions options = new SubscribeOptions.Builder()
    .setStrategy(Strategy.BLE_ONLY)
    // Note: If no filter is specified, Nearby will return all of your
    // attachments regardless of type. You must use a filter to specify
    // a particular set of attachments (by type) or to fetch attachments
    // in a namespace other than your project's default.
    .setFilter(new MessageFilter.Builder()
        .includeNamespacedType("some_namespace", "some_type")
        .build())
    .build();
```